# Using pivot table output?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, statistics, geoprocessing-framework

In an attempt to summarise landclasses, the columns of my pivot table output are a bit mixed up with the field info regarding the three input fields that I've selected. As shown in snapshot 3 the description field have the info of the grid_slo field, the grid_slo field have the info of the grid_alt field, and grid-alt showing zero. The original descriptions that should show under the descriptio field has been lost. Numerous attempts to fix this problem has been unsuccessful. Can anyone help please?

[image: attribute table]
[image: pivot table input]

[image: snapshot showing the output, with the description field having the info of the grid_slo field, the grid_slo field having the info of the grid_alt field, and grid-alt showing zero. The original descriptions that should show under the descriptio field has been lost]

Comment: I think this is just a case of reading the help file. You are pivoting on FID AND populating by FID. Make a cup of coffee, sit down and look at the help for this tool, look at the image and the inputs and outputs. See that their PIVOT field is different to their VALUE field. It's a head scratcher but you'll get there.

Comment: Alternatively you could consider using [Summarize](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000055000000) on the Descriptions column with whatever statistic you're trying to calculate on the slope and alt fields, rather than the [Pivot Table tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000n8000000).  Or perhaps the [Frequency tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001w000000) if you need/have access to it.

Comment: The Frequency tool worked perfectly. Thank you all for your input and suggestions. Now just to figure out how to relate the frequency table back to the original shapefile layer to present each summarised row in a unique colour coding (i.e. for the different summarised polygons).